# How to impelement referenced assemblies to codedom in C#

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, dllimport, codedom

I want to use CodeDom technology. But, I couldn't find the correct way to impelement referenced assemblies to my dynamic code. Everything is ok if I write just simple declaration code (e.x `return "test"`). But when I want to use MessabeBox compiler result error contains `The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context`

```
 StringBuilder sbCode = new StringBuilder();

 sbCode.Append("public class Test {");
 sbCode.Append(tbCode.Text);
 sbCode.Append("}");
var cp = new CompilerParameters()
{
   GenerateInMemory = true,
   GenerateExecutable = false,
   ReferencedAssemblies =
    {
     "System.dll",
      "System.Core.dll",
      "System.Windows.dll",
      "System.Windows.Forms.dll"
    }
  };

  using (CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
   {
     CompilerResults res = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sbCode.ToString());
     var type = res.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Test"); 
     var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
     var output = type.GetMethod("Execute").Invoke(obj, new object[] { });
   }
```

And here is my sample code which I write in tbCode text box:

```
public string Execute()
{
 MessageBox.Show("adsf");
return "asdf";
}
```

Comment: The references just link the dlls. Did you try to add the using statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the required "using" statements at the begining of the class declaration:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

You can also call the MessageBox using the full namespace:

```
public string Execute()
{
 System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("adsf");
return "asdf";
}
```

Comment: It works very well thanks alot. If I want to use a custom object as return type? For example I have class library in my solution and I want to return a class by using code dome. I tried give the library namespace just like system but it doesnt work.